# Convergence of the sum of a family of real-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, sequences-and-series

Let $\phi_1,...,\phi_n,...$ be a sequence of real-valued functions so that $\phi_j:[0,1)\to[0,1)$, $\phi_j(0)=0$, and $\phi_j(\delta)$ converges to 0 as $\delta$ approaches 0 from the right for all $j\ge1$. Further suppose that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \phi_j(\delta)$ **converges** and moreover, is strictly **smaller** than 1 for an **arbitrary** $\delta$ in $(0,1)$.

---

**MY QUESTION** is:

Does it hold that $\lim_{\delta\to0^+} \sum_{j=1}^\infty \phi_j(\delta)=0$  ? If it doesn't, then does it turn out to be true if we in addition require that $\lim_{\delta\to0^+}{\phi_j(\delta) \over \delta}=0$ for all $j\ge1$?

---

The sequence satisfying $\phi_j(\delta)=\delta^j$ for all $j\ge1$, which gave me some kind of intuition, does support the equality, but I guess the equality does not hold true in general and I've been stuck in disproving it for days... Now I **really** need someone to show me a complete and detailed proof or disproof... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Something like $\phi_j(\delta)=\delta/(100j), \delta \le 1/(\log j+1), \delta/(100 \times 2^j) , \delta > 1/(\log j+1)$ smoothed out if needed to make it continuous should give a counterxample since the sum should be greater than $1/200$ say for all positive small $\delta$ and less than $1/50$ or so

Answer (score 1):

consider $\phi(x)=x$ then consider $$\lim_{n->\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\phi(1/n) = \lim\ n/n = 1$$

I hope it's easy to see that $$\lim_{\delta -> 0^+}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \phi_j(\delta) \ge \lim_{n->\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\phi(1/n) = 1$$ of course you can take sum $$\lim_{n->\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\phi(1/n) = \lim_{n -> \infty}n =\infty$$

probably it needs some low level explanations why we can point these sums in this situation but it should be correct